# Oracle DBMS_LOB: Using DBMS_LOB.convertToBlob multiple times in PLSQL block

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, blob

When I try to use `DBMS_LOB.convertToBlob` procedure multiple times in the same PLSQL block only the first execution works as expected. All additional executions produce empty blobs. Here is an example:

```
DECLARE 

v_temp1 varchar2(32767) := 'absd'; 
V_temp1_blob BLOB; 
V_temp2 varchar2(32767) := 'efghi'; 
V_temp2_blob BLOB;

v_in      integer := 1;
v_out     integer := 1;
v_lang    integer := 0;
v_warning integer := 0;

BEGIN

DBMS_LOB.createTemporary (V_temp1_blob, TRUE);  
DBMS_LOB.convertToBlob(V_temp1_blob, V_temp1, DBMS_LOB.LOBMAXSIZE, v_in, v_out, DBMS_LOB.DEFAULT_CSID, v_lang, v_warning);
dbms_output.put_line('V_temp1_blob: ' || dbms_lob.getlength(V_temp1_blob));

DBMS_LOB.createTemporary (V_temp2_blob, TRUE);
DBMS_LOB.convertToBlob(V_temp2_blob, V_temp2, DBMS_LOB.LOBMAXSIZE, v_in, v_out, DBMS_LOB.DEFAULT_CSID, v_lang, v_warning);
dbms_output.put_line('V_temp2_blob: ' || dbms_lob.getlength(V_temp2_blob));

END;
```

OUTPUT:

```
V_temp1_blob: 4
V_temp2_blob: 0
```

My expected output is:

```
V_temp1_blob: 4
V_temp2_blob: 5
```

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `v_in` and `v_out` local variables are being passed in as the `dest_offset` and `src_offset` parameters of the `convertToBlob` procedure.  These are `in out` parameters so they are modified by the call.

`dest_offset`, which is what you're passing `v_in` for, is defined to be

> (IN)Offset in bytes in the destination LOB for the start of the write.
>   Specify a value of 1 to start at the beginning of the LOB.
>
> (OUT)The new offset in bytes after the end of the write.

while `src_offset`, which is what you're passing `v_out` for, is defined to be

> (IN)Offset in characters in the source LOB for the start of the read.
>
> (OUT)Offset in characters in the source LOB right after the end of the
>   read.

For the first call, you're passing in 1 in both cases.  For the second call, you're passing in the offsets from the first LOB.  You'd need to re-initialize both parameters to 1 before making the second call.

I'd also suggest that you probably want to choose better variable names than `v_in` and `v_out` for these variables.  If they were named `v_src_offset` and `v_dest_offset`, that would generally make your code clearer and might make the bug easier to spot.