# Oracle 11g: Comparing two *LOB columns of different types

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, blob, clob, lob

I've got read-only access to a database containing two schema with tables like this:

```
schema1.A.unique_id, schema1.A.content
schema2.B.unique_id, schema2.B.content
```

`A.unique_id` and `B.unique_id` will match while `A.content` and `B.content` are `*LOB` columns that should match (wasn't my idea lol).  What I'd like to do is compare the contents of the `content` fields and see how many are equal.  However, one is a `CLOB` and one is a `BLOB`.

`DBMS_LOB.COMPARE()` is an obvious helper, however it only compares two `*LOB`s of the same type (e.g. `CLOB` vs. `CLOB`).

In lieu of writing a script to get the content of the fields and compare them in memory, how can I perform this comparison in straight-up PL/SQL?  Is there some way I can convert one of the fields on-the-fly so that the types match (again keep in mind I only have read-only access)?

Thanks!

Comment: At a minimum, you'd need to know how to convert the `CLOB` into a `BLOB`-- the binary representation could be using a different character set which is why the `convertToCLOB` method takes a character set parameter.  You could call `dbms_lob.convertToCLOB` on the BLOB columns (or `convertToBLOB` on the CLOB columns) and then compare but that isn't going to be hugely efficient.

Comment: @JustinCave Can I use `convertToCLOB()` if I don't have write access?  Or do you think comparing it in memory on the local machine with a script will be faster than doing `convertToCLOB()` + `compare()`?

Comment: `dbms_lob.convertToCLOB` doesn't write anything.  Assuming you can write an anonymous PL/SQL block, you can use local `clob` (or `blob`) variables.

Comment: Ok I see.  I found another answer of yours (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31902029/oracle-dbms-lob-using-dbms-lob-converttoblob-multiple-times-in-plsql-block) and it looks like I need to store the converted output in a pre-defined `BLOB`.  Maybe I should just write a script lol.  Thanks for your help :D